Chrome fails to connect with ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH, but firefox can connect
I am trying to connect to a local server with server certificate signed by a self-signed CA.
And I am getting this error: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH in Chrome, and the following logs from server:
[2024-04-02T00:34:30.493881Z ERROR pingora_core::services::listening]
Downstream handshake error  TLSHandshakeFailure context: TLS accept()
failed: error:0A000076:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:no suitable
signature algorithm:ssl/t1_lib.c:3725:

This is server certificate:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            6c:bf:34:cc:33:4c:71:1c:7d:ab:ff:0a:c8:e0:3c:9f:01:a3:ee:e2
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA512
        Issuer: CN = CA-fqmo
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr  1 21:30:44 2024 GMT
            Not After : Mar  8 21:30:44 2124 GMT
        Subject: O = server-elgy
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (521 bit)
                pub:
                    04:01:b3:03:d8:00:aa:a4:06:c4:bf:b4:b1:12:7b:
                    ...
                ASN1 OID: secp521r1
                NIST CURVE: P-521
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:asdf.qwer, DNS:zxcv.qwer, IP Address:127.0.0.1
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                15:89:9B:82:3F:F4:3C:2D:BF:B0:BD:15:2B:52:6F:FD:08:47:D9:25
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                DC:48:6F:99:75:57:B5:34:1D:D0:6A:E2:7F:60:C6:9F:6A:5C:EC:4B
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA512
    Signature Value:
        30:65:02:30:33:25:2d:80:be:13:de:19:5a:68:dd:c5:d9:7a:
        ...

So, it uses "Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA512".
I also tried comparing client hello message between firefox (which works) and chrome (by running this server: openssl s_server -cert ~/devel/pingora-tests/keys/server-cert.pem -key ~/devel/pingora-tests/keys/server-key.pem -accept 6189 -WWW  -state  -tlsextdebug)
this is the most suspicious difference
chrome sends this:
TLS client extension "signature algorithms" (id=13), len=18
0000 - 00 10 04 03 08 04 04 01-05 03 08 05 05 01 08 06   ................
0010 - 06 01                                             ..

while ff sends this:
TLS client extension "signature algorithms" (id=13), len=24
0000 - 00 16 04 03 05 03 06 03-08 04 08 05 08 06 04 01   ................
0010 - 05 01 06 01 02 03 02 01-                          ........

According to this site and this, ECDSA/SECP521r1/SHA512 is encoded as 06 03, and indeed, there is 06 03 in FF, but not in chrome.


Can anyone please tell me what is going on? Does Chrome not support ecdsa-with-SHA512 signature algorithm?
How can I check which signature algorithms it supports?
Is there any particular reason for why it does not support it?
Is there any way to make Chrome work with it?


See https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html for what a browser supports. Or check with Wireshark. And no, Chrome does not seem to support it. As for the motivation see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/security-dev/c/SlfABuvvQas/m/qOil2X4UBQAJ: "Hashes larger than SHA-256 (respectively, SHA-384) signed with P-256 (respectively, P-384) get truncated to size, so the larger hash is not useful. Moreover, TLS 1.3 will prohibit ECDSA curve/hash mismatches, so this change aligns our TLS 1.2 and 1.3 advertisements."

@SteffenUllrich nice, thank you! (If you make this an answer, I will upvote and accept it as an answer.)

@SteffenUllrich, by the way, any ideas why this is the case: "However, we only support P-256 and P-384 for ECDSA curves"? Do you have any insights into why Chrome decided not to support P-521?

never mind, apparently P-521 is not a part of "suite B": "While P-521 is valid for use in X.509 certificates, most browsers dropped support for it as it is not a part of Suite B and isn't very popular"
